# CocoaPods install ShareKit issue

Tags: ios, sharekit, cocoapods

I got this message in my terminal. I have setup ShareKit before for empty project and it was installed without any issues.

[image]

```
[!] From now on use `Quiz.xcworkspace`.

[!] The target `Quiz [Debug]` overrides the `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Pods.xcconfig'.
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The target `Quiz [Debug - Release]` overrides the `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Pods.xcconfig'.
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.
Alexanders-Mac-Pro:Quiz alexander$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have somehow previously set different values for header_search_paths and that value needs to be changed to $(inherited) to inherit the Cocoapods header search paths settings.

See the Cocoapods FAQ
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/wiki/Creating-a-project-that-uses-CocoaPods#faq

[image: Screenshot of xcode build settings]

Comment: thanks for your answer. yes I see what's the problem. but what do I do? Which steps do I need?

Comment: I have changed $(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2 to $(inherited)/usr/include/libxml2 in my aap target but right now it says #import <libxml/tree.h> file not found

Comment: Ya that won't work.  You need to add two paths, one that is $(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2
and one that is just
$(inherited)